# Query to get the details by matching date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Hi I am have converted the string to date format and trying to match by date and get the customer details but nothing is matching.

```
 $beginTimeStamp =  "1524853800";
 $endTimeStamp = "1525717800";
 $beginTime = date('Y-m-d', $beginTimeStamp);
 $beginTimeStamp = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($beginTime . ' +1 day'));
 $endTime = date('Y-m-d', $endTimeStamp);
 $endTimeStamp = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($endTime . ' +1 day'));

 $userDetails = DB::select('SELECT * from users where created_at >='.$beginTimeStamp.' AND created_at <= '.$endTimeStamp.'');
```

The date is coming by using below SQL query when I am using PHP variable.

Comment: Where is the `t1` table coming from?

Comment: Sorry By mistake it was written during posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates seem fine, they are in sql format.

The missing semicolon i guess it is just a "mistake" in copy paste otherwise you would get an error.

```
$userDetails = DB::select("SELECT * from users where created_at >={$beginTimeStamp} AND created_at <= {$endTimeStamp}");
```

Try this query. I think the error is coming from the way you try to concatenate the variables with the query and that you don't enclose your query with double quotes.

This query should also work:

```
$userDetails = DB::select("SELECT * from users where created_at >='$beginTimeStamp' AND t1.created_at <= '$endTimeStamp'");
```

The whole query is enclosed in double quotes and the variables inside single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Prince.  its a double quotes fault.

Comment: Glad i helped. Please accept my answer if it solved your question.

Comment: To accept it you must select the "tick symbol" under my answer score. Otherwise this question will be marked without an answer for future users that have the same question as yours.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

@Maneesh Rao,

Seem like few syntax errors in code.

- `$endTime = date('Y-m-d', $endTimeStamp)` **missing semi-colon.**
- 'SELECT * from users where created_at >='.$beginTimeStamp.' AND t1.created_at <= '.$endTimeStamp.  -- **Why t1?**

Try this once

```
"SELECT * from users where created_at >='" . $beginTimeStamp."' AND created_at <='". $endTimeStamp."'";
```

  -

Comment: Sorry for that. Syntax error coming during posting the question. Now I have edited the code. please check once.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Laravel so use the query builder and `Carbon`:

```
$beginTimeStamp =  "1524853800";
$endTimeStamp = "1525717800"; 
$userDetails = DB::table("users")
     ->where("created_at", ">=",  Carbon::createFromTimestamp($beginTimeStamp)->addDay())
     ->where("created_at", "<=",  Carbon::createFromTimestamp($endTimeStamp )->addDay())
     ->get();
```